# php3 in Debian 3.0 on a raspberry pi using QEMU

Tags: php, linux, raspbian, qemu

yes, my question is VERY esoteric. I get that. But for good reasons I have to get Debian 3.0 running on a raspberry pi. Actually i'm fine with any solution that gets me a modern browser connecting to LAMP with php3 on a raspi to be honest but I figured just running an old linux image in a QEMU container would be the way to go.
(Getting a 16 year old media arts project to work on a modern computer and no, it's not going to be exposed to the internet)
I am using raspbian as the base. However, booting up the debian 3.0r6 cd:

```
qemu-system-i386 -hda hda.img -cdrom debian-30r6-i386-binary-1.iso -boot d -m 256
```

The image boots but the keyboard is totally screwed. No single key is where it should be. I'm using a standard mac usb keybaord. 
any hints? Alternatively: Any hints on how to get php3/apache1 running on a raspberry pi?

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly add a keymap (`-k en`). See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU#Keyboard_seems_broken_or_the_arrow_keys_do_not_work for more details.